# How to transfer the value of the string from thread to another?

Tags: java, android, multithreading, jsoup

I am using Jsoup to parse a part of a website and then put it into a string. I want to visualize this string into a textView, but since only the thread that had created the textView can modify it i need to pass the value of the string into the main thread. how?

This is the code: (ignore the tabhost stuff)

```
public class NewsAndAnnouncements extends Activity {

    TabHost host;
    FlyOutContainer container;
    Button bttoggle;
    Button bt1;
    String loggity;
    TextView tv1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.container = (FlyOutContainer) this.getLayoutInflater().inflate(
                R.layout.newsandannouncements, null);
        this.setContentView(container);

        host = (TabHost) findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
        host.setup();

        TabSpec specs = host.newTabSpec("TAGGITY EINZ");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab1);
        specs.setIndicator("News");
        host.addTab(specs);

        specs = host.newTabSpec("TAGGITY ZWEI");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab2);
        specs.setIndicator("Notices");
        host.addTab(specs);

        specs = host.newTabSpec("TAGGITY DREI");
        specs.setContent(R.id.tab3);
        specs.setIndicator("Events");
        host.addTab(specs);

        tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        /*
         * bttoggle = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttoggle); bt1 = (Button)
         * findViewById(R.id.Button1);
         * 
         * bttoggle.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         * 
         * @Override public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method
         * container.toggleMenu(); } });
         * 
         * bt1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
         * 
         * @Override public void onClick(View v) { // TODO Auto-generated method
         * container.toggleMenu(); } });
         */

        Thread newsThread = new Thread() { 
            public void run() {

                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup
                            .connect(
                                    "http://acs.bg/Home/About_ACS/News_and_Events/News.aspx")
                            .get();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Elements myin = doc.getElementsByClass("news_list");
                loggity = myin.toString();


                        Log.i("ELEMENTS HTML", loggity);

            }
        };
        newsThread.start();

        tv1.setText(loggity);

    }

}
```

Comment: what's wrong with the code posted

Comment: the textView doesn't visualize anything. It's empty - hence I concluded that the string comes out empty at the end. The textView works with any other string i create outside of the thread. AND i know that the myin.toString(); method produces values as I can see the string in the log.

Comment: Consider using a AsyncTask instead of a 'raw' thread: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: what do you see in the log. do you see `Log.i("ELEMENTS HTML", loggity);`?

Comment: i see the string and it's ok, it shows the html

Comment: you are setting the text to textview just after the thread starts.

Comment: how can i set the text to the textview after the thread FINISHES?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) instead of the Thread. To modify views on your ui thread use the [runOnUiThread()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread%28java.lang.Runnable%29) method in your activity.

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        tv1.setText("...");
    }
});
```

Comment: AsyncTask is fine, but running it on the UI thread is a bad idea as UI will be frozen while the task is running!

Comment: To clarify, the `runOnUiThread` is only used, to change the text of the textview, not for the AsyncTask

Comment: that works. Thank you!! can't upvote your answer since i don't have the reputation

Comment: where should I write this part ?

Comment: and if you want it to change the view each second how can I add that

Answer (score 1):

Use an AsyncTask instead of a raw Thread:

```
new AsyncTask<URL, Object, Document>() {
    protected Document doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        // parse URL and return document
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
        // this runs in UI thread
        // show document in UI
    }
}).execute(myURL);
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways to d it-

1)- Using AsyncTask

2)- Using Handler

```
Thread newsThread = new Thread() 
{ 
            public void run() 
            {
                Document doc = null;
                try {
                    doc = Jsoup
                            .connect(
                                    "http://acs.bg/Home/About_ACS/News_and_Events/News.aspx")
                            .get();
                } 
                catch (IOException e) 
                {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Elements myin = doc.getElementsByClass("news_list");
                loggity = myin.toString();

                mHandler.post(new Runnable() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run() 
                    {
                            try 
                            {
                                    tv1.setText(loggity);
                            } catch (Exception e) 
                            {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
            });
            Log.i("ELEMENTS HTML", loggity);
            }
        };
        newsThread.start();
```

You can initialize the Hanlder in the start.

Comment: thank you. I already found an answer but I will experiment with this and maybe try your way too! thanks again :)

Answer (score 1):

try this sample code, don't know if this is the better way:

```
public class MainThread {


public static void main(String args[]) {
    Thread2 t2 = new Thread2();
    Thread nextThread = new Thread(t2);
    nextThread.start();

    try {
        nextThread.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println();
    System.out.println(t2.getStr());

}

private static class Thread2 implements Runnable{
    private String str;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        setStr("T2 Thread String");

    }
    public String getStr() {
        return str;
    }
    public void setStr(String str) {
        this.str = str;
    }

}


}
```